# IPC connection to browser process is lost - loadrunner

Tags: ipc, loadrunner, truclient

I am using loadrunner 12.02 - truclient for IE - on a set of virtual machines. All machines are hosted on an ESXi 5.5 (tested with E1000 and VMXnet3 interfaces).
Load generator: Windows 2012 R2 (also tried with Windows 2008 R2)
Web server: Windows 2012 R2 
The testing scenario is pretty simple - 4 users login and start to execute a set of steps (loading submissions and submitting them).
However, on every test-run, after 2-15 minutes of running at least one of the threads gets "IPC connection to browser process is lost" and stops.
In the resource monitor I can see that 2 threads of loadrunner have entered into deadlock.
There is not anti-virus software on any of the servers and IPv6 is disabled as it is famous for triggering strange issues.
Happy to hear from you guys! Thanks!

Comment: This is a C++ issue whereby the magic LoadRunner is using to send messages cross-process is tanking.  There's not much you can do but to experiment to find who's killing the necessary thread.  Sometimes, it's the supporting code, in which case, you'd have to open a ticket with HP.  (Not a promising option).

Comment: Hi tsveti - Any response from HP on this?

Comment: I had like 5-6 phone sessions with HP, but to no avail :( It turned out that this a generic error, thrown in many situations. We tried to apply hot-fixes, to upgrade to 12.50, to use different identification methods when clicking on javascript links, I even added unneeded waits between the steps, but the issue persisted. The HP guy admitted that he can't understand what's going on

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most likely related to Microsoft updates KB3049563 & KB3038314.
As an initial measure I suggest uninstalling those updates. Then please contact HP Support, we already published an hotfix for this issue.

Regards,
Shlomi Nissim
HP TruClient R&D Manager

Comment: Could you please link to this hotfix, or describe it, so that future visitors won't have to contact you directly to get this?

Comment: The issue is reproduced when these two updates are uninstalled. I contacted HP and now I am waiting. If they come up with something I will post the answer here.